# Image transport to android consumes high memory

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I tried to run simple image_transport tutorial on my android 4.0 phone to display image captured by camera. It connects with the master, it displays the image, but the frame rate is extremely low and eventually device hangs itself. It seems that the app is using a lot of memory and therefore GC_FOR_ALLOC pauses the execution of the program. I suppose that each image received is stored instead of being removed after the frame is used.
Can anybody help me to fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65183/image-transport-to-android-consumes-high-memory/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is here:
http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=141

It is needed to make RosImageView a SurfaceView instead of an ImageView.

---

Originally posted by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) with karma: 141 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0